# When i refresh page my api key remove value

Tags: vue.js

I need not to remove the api Key when refreshing the page and this is my code
[image]

Comment: Don't share code as screenshots. Try and create a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**, explain the problem clearly, and share what you've tried so far. You should also take a look at **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: What do you want to do here exactly? Deleting it on the front-end with a `setTimeout` is probably not a good idea anyway. Your backend should invalidate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to get your previously added cookies and dispatch them on mounted events. Add this lines:

```js
computed: {
  apiKey() {
    return this.$store.getters['getApiKey'];·
  },
methods: {
  setApiKey(apiKey) {
    this.$store.dispatch('setApiKey', apiKey);
  },
  singIn() {
    loginUsers(this.email, this.password, this.setApiKey);·
    setTimeout(() => ·{
      this.$cookies.set('apiKey', this.apiKey, {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 31536000,
      }),
    }, 1000);
  },
},
mounted() {
  let apiKey = this.$cookies.get('apiKey'); // Get previously set cookies
  this.$store.dispatch('setApiKey', apiKey); // Dispatch action
}
```